# Getting all combinations from a list using recusion, including combinations that use the same number

Tags: java, recursion

I have a list of numbers: `[10, 13, 15]`. I am trying to find the combinations of numbers in the list that add up to or are less than the target of 28.

Currently I have a recursive method:

```
    public void combinations(ArrayList<Integer>data,int fromIndex, int endIndex)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int target = 28;
    ArrayList<Integer>results = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if(fromIndex == endIndex)
    {
        return;
    }

    for(int currentIndex = fromIndex; currentIndex < endIndex; currentIndex++)
    {
        if(sum + data.get(currentIndex) <= target)
        {
            results.add(data.get(currentIndex));
            sum +=data.get(currentIndex);
        }

    }

    System.out.println(results);
    combinations(data, fromIndex + 1, endIndex);
}
```

Currently this outputs:
`[10, 13],[13, 15],[15]` which are correct and I understand why I am getting these solutions as my recursive method has a +1. However other solutions such as `[10],[13],[10,10]` ect are not included and I was wondering how I would go about implementing this, would I need to change my increments in my recursive method?

Comment: @[Danny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8747735/danny) are you sure about [10,10] not [10,15]

Comment: @BrijRajKishore [10, 10] would be a valid solution as this equals 20, which is less than 28 making it correct.

Comment: @[Danny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8747735/danny) then it will become infinite recursion for 0 and negative numbers

Comment: Are you expecting sets of 2 numbers only or can the combination include 3 or more numbers as well? ex: Is the output [5,10,13] valid for input [5,10,13,15] ?

Comment: @Lihini your example wouldnt be valid, as the total of this list exeeds the target value of 28, valid solutions would be: [5, 10], [10, 13] ect... as these are equal or less than the target value

Comment: I'm confused.. 5+10+13 = 28

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void combinations(ArrayList<Integer> arr, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ans, int startIndex, int endIndex, int sum) {
    
    if(startIndex > endIndex) {
        for(ArrayList<Integer> x : ans) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        return;
    }
     ArrayList<Integer> newTemp;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> newAns = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    for(ArrayList<Integer> x : ans) {
        newAns.add(x);
    }
    for(ArrayList<Integer> x : ans) {
        int s = 0;
        newTemp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(Integer v : x) {
            newTemp.add(v);
            s+=v;
        }
        if(s + arr.get(startIndex) <= sum) {
            newTemp.add(arr.get(startIndex));
            newAns.add(newTemp);
        }
    }
    
    if(arr.get(startIndex) <= sum ) {
        newTemp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        newTemp.add(arr.get(startIndex));
        newAns.add(newTemp);
    }
    
    combinations(arr,newAns, startIndex+1, endIndex, sum);
}
```

I have to rewrite your code as I was unable to think through your code.

Secondly, I have to make a newArrayList all time to avoid [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) which I have faced the first time and will overcome later after gaining some knowledge about it.

Now, this method should be called as

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    arr.add(10);
    arr.add(15);
    arr.add(13);
    arr.add(-5);
    arr.add(28);
    combinations(arr, new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(), 0, 4, 28);
}
```

Explanation: I have generalized your question's answer to fit any sum in int range.
I have made ArrayList of ArrayList which will print all the combinations at the base case.

1. I have first added an ArrayList containing single element i.e current element if the current element is the <= sum.
2. Then with all remaining ArrayList, I have calculated the sum of each and then check whether adding the current element into the previous ArrayList holds the above condition.
3. At the same time I have made new ArrayList and copied all elements while I was calculating the sum of each ArrayList and then if the second case holds good then I added the current element into temp ArrayList and then added the temp ArrayList to the answer ArrayList of ArrayLists.
4. Then I called the recursion by incrementing the startIndex by 1.

Comment: This is great, thank you very much! Much better solution than mine. How would it work if I wanted to return the arraylist of an arraylist?

Comment: @Danny but this does not include the results you are asking such as 10,10. I have got the approach and I am framing answer for it. And if you want to return ArrayList of ArrayLists you have to start building from the base case. In base case the arrayList will be of size 1 or 0 and return it. Then use that Arraylist to add elements to each arrayLists (depending on condition).

Comment: @Danny please upvote and mark it as accepted if it solved your issue and I will update answer which will also solve the problem including 10,10. It will take time. I will update it later.